# Eliminar Valores en Cero de un Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Teniendo lo siguiente:

```
$array_id_mat   = Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$array_cant_mat = Array('1','0','0','3','1','0','0','0','0','1');
```

En donde se resume lo siguiente:

1. $array_id_mat son los id de una serie materiales contenidos en una tabla tb1.
2. $array_cant_mat son las cantidades que corresponden a los id de los materiales de la tabla tb1, es decir:

- El id 1, tiene 1 material.
- El id 2, tiene 0 materiales.
- El id 3, tiene 0 materiales.
- El id 4, tiene 3 materiales.
- Asi sucesivamente ...

Lo que necesito hacer es sacar, eliminar o dejar de lado los id de $array_id_mat que tengan 0 (cero) cantidad de materiales y dejar solo los id que posean 1 o mas materiales, para luego comparar esos ids con los de otra tabla, de manera que pueda listar solo el nombre del material y su cantidad, siempre y cuando esta sea mayor o igual 1 como mencione anteriormente.

Alguien me puede orientar o ayudar a como realizar este proceso?
Agradecido como siempre por su ayuda.

Comment: Crea un array asociativo con clave id y valor la cantidad. Luego aplica un array_filter sobre ese array con un método que devuelva true si el valor es <0. Ten cuidado porque tus arrays iniciales son cadena, no enteros.

Comment: @Jakala gracias por responder. Como creas un array asociativo a partir de 2 array contenidos en variables diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recorrer `$array_id_mat` en un bucle, verificar si el valor que corresponde en `$array_cant_mat` es mayor que `0` para guardar de forma asociativa la llave de  `$array_id_mat` y el valor respectivo de `$array_cant_mat` en un nuevo array.

Por ejemplo:

```
$array_id_mat   = Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
$array_cant_mat = Array('1','0','0','3','1','0','0','0','0','1');
$newArray=array();
foreach ($array_id_mat as $k=>$v){
    /*
        Verificamos si el valor correspondiente 
        en $array_cant_mat es mayor que 0
    */
    if ($array_cant_mat[$k]>0){
        /*
            Si lo es asociamos los valores en $newArray
        */
        $newArray[$v]=$array_cant_mat[$k];
    
    }
}
/* Imprimimos para prueba */
print_r($newArray);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

Comment: Estimado, agradecido como siempre por tu ayuda. A simple vista y haciendo una prueba muy simple, me ha funcionado. Ahora realizare mas pruebas para verificar que todo este ok. Muchas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Para qué un ciclo? Era suficiente con `$newArray = array_filter($array_cant_mat);`

Comment: @Triby `array_filter` por sí solo no excluye los valores que son `0` debes en ese caso manipular de nuevo el array final para sacar esos valores.

Comment: Probé ese y también `array_filter($array_cant_mat, function($var) { return $var != 0; })` con los mismos resultados. Sin función, elimina los valores equiparables a `false`: Cero, null, cadena vacía, false, etc. [Referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @Triby excelente. Ignoraba ese modo de `array_filter`. Sugiero que lo agregues como respuesta, así se ofrecen dos modos distintos para resolver el problema. Aunque no es *sin función*, estás implementando una función. Queda pendiente el punto del rendimiento, en el caso de un uso recurrente y/o con muchos datos.

Comment: En el primer ejemplo, lo usé sin función, el segundo es con función anónima. En cuanto a rendimiento, es equiparable al _for_.